# Uber API - Request Map - Sandbox

Tags: uber-api

I'm just testing the new request endpoints and am wondering what return I can expect from the Map request?

https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/#request-map

I am currently testing things with the sandbox and the returned URL doesn't appear to work. ( https://sandbox.api.uber.com/eta/8Ah3gR7MT ) I am not sure if this is the case because it's the Sandbox or.. ?

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox returns a [static map image](https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/map) that can be used to render inside of your application as you would in production.

In production, the map will be more responsive and interactive, showing the car traveling on the map and the ETA to destination.

Comment: Im using the sand-box api and manually changing the Request Status via { PUT /v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id} } accepted and arriving is working fine. but in_progress not working, I am getting this out put  status code: 503, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 78;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Server = nginx;
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    "X-Uber-App" = "uberex-sandbox";
    "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} } What could be the reason

Comment: @Scott Biggart Any updates as to when the Sandbox API will support */v1/requests/{request_id}/map* endpoint?